Some tailwindcss class working some don't
import React from 'react'

function InputBox({
    label,
    className = "",
    currency,
    currencyOptions,
    amount,
    onValueChange,
    onCurrencyChange
}) {

    return (
        <div className={`bg-white p-3 rounded-lg text-sm flex`} style={{justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
            <div className="w-1/2">
                <label className="mb-2 inline-block">
                    {label}
                </label>
                <input

                    className="outline-none w-full bg-transparent py-1.5"
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="Amount"
                    value={amount}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        onValueChange(e.target.value)
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="w-1/2">
                <p className="text-gray-500">Currency Type</p>
                <select
                    className="rounded-lg px-1 py-1 bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer outline-none"
                    value={currency}
                    onChange={(e)=> onCurrencyChange(e.target.value)}
                >
                    {currencyOptions.map((curr) => (
                        <option value={curr} key={curr}>
                            {curr.toUpperCase()}
                        </option>
                    ))}


                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default InputBox;

In the first div, justify-between was not working so I had to use inline styling and now the second div with class w-1/2 contains p in which only text-white or text-black is working and not any other color. Please help, it's very frustrating.

I can confirm to you that everything you have mentioned that doesn't work in your code actually works. I have just reproduced your code and it's working fine. You might want to take a look at your Tailwindcss configuration: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

make sure that you are running the CLI tool
